# can't access Magento homepage and Admin, 404 not Found

Tags: magento, admin

I got this error in my system.log file

> Recoverable Error: Argument 1 passed to
>   Mage_Core_Model_Store::setWebsite() must be an instance of
>   Mage_Core_Model_Website

and i found this solution to set default store

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
UPDATE `core_store` SET store_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE `core_store_group` SET group_id = 0 WHERE name='Default';
UPDATE `core_website` SET website_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE `customer_group` SET customer_group_id = 0 WHERE customer_group_code='NOT LOGGED IN';
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

But it steel don't work !!

Even whene i try to get the Admin page "Magento/index.php/admin" it get me back to the homePage with a 404 Not Found in the content

can you help please ! Thanks

Comment: check once whether your database import was successful.i too got this issue.so i tried updating same solution you tried.but it was not done.so when i checked table this records was not their.so i had imported themysql again.then it is solved for me.i hope this will also help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone ! but it was an .htaccess issue

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the 'local database remote imported problem' where local id values of 0 are remotely set to the next available id value. To tackle this add to your SQL dump file (first line) the line `SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";` and import it again.

Answer (score 0):

1) Navigate to the following file and delete it.

> app/etc/use_cache.ser

[more info](http://www.magentodeveloperleedsuk.co.uk/recoverable-error-argument-1-passed-to-mage-code-model-store-setwebsite/)